# MySql: Select from a table when week is actual week, and the week before

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table where a column is "Week", and I want to select all the rows of the table where "Week" is the current week and also the week before.

For instance, today is 15/02/2017 so, it is week 7. I want to select all the rows where "Week" Between 6 and 7 , but without writting the numbers, so it will change with the current week.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Add some sample table data (as well formatted text), and also the expected result.

Comment: please look this link ,to know more details on how to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL
WHERE [WEEK_COLUMN] BETWEEEN WEEK(CURDATE())-1 AND WEEK(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot!